# Connect GND/signal-output-pins to differential-input-pins

Tags: ground, differential

I have a device outputting a signal (-10V...+10V) referring to GND. Now I want to feed this signal into another device, that only accepts differential inputs (-10V...+10V).

Is it possible to just connect GND to one of the diff. input-pins and signal to the other diff. input-pin? Is there something completly wrong with this attempt?

Edit: Both devices are connected to a common ground.

Answer (score 2):

When both devices are not connected in any other way except for their output and input  terminals, you can just connect as described: connect GND to one of the diff. input-pins and signal to the other diff. input-pin.

*connections in any other way* include shared earth or chasis or signal ground.

**EDIT after new presented information**
Devices that allow for differential inputs sometimes also specify an allowable common mode voltage. Check the datasheet of the input device for this allowed common mode voltage.

Comment: Actually they are connected to a common ground. What problem will this cause?

Comment: Do *edit* your question with this relevant information. The more information you provide, the more useful answer you get.